# Hibernate <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> - drop Table if exists hangs for ever

Tags: hibernate

I was writing a sample hibernate program with hbm2ddl.create property with "Create" / "create-drop" value in the hibernate configuration file. I thought every execution of the  program will drop the table and create a new table. But it does not work as expected. When I run for the first time, it creates the table nicely.

But when I run the same program again, the Drop table hbm2ddl schema export tablename if exists sql hangs for ever. For every run, Im forced to restart the DB server. (Mysql in this case.) Is this because of some Transaction issue ?

Below is the sample program

### Configuration File :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/localdb</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="show_sql">True</property>
 <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>(Tried create and create-drop.Both behaves the same way/)-->
     <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
  <mapping resource="com/test/manytomany/domain/TemporalTest.hbm.xml"/>
<!--    <mapping resource="com/test/manytomany/domain/Event.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="com/test/manytomany/domain/Person.hbm.xml"/>
 --> </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HBM File:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Jun 11, 2014 7:09:00 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.manytomany.domain.TemporalTest" table="TEMPORAL_TEST">
        <id name="temporalID" type="int">
            <column name="TEMPORAL_ID" />
        </id>
        <property name="temporalDate" >
            <column name="TEMPORAL_DATE" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### Pojo Class:-

```
package com.test.manytomany.domain;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

public class TemporalTest {


    private int temporalID;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Time temporalDate;


    public TemporalTest(){}
    /**
     * @return the temporalID
     */
    public int getTemporalID() {
        return temporalID;
    }
    /**
     * @param temporalID the temporalID to set
     */
    public void setTemporalID(int temporalID) {
        this.temporalID = temporalID;
    }

    /**
     * @return the temporalDate
     */
    public Time getTemporalDate() {
        return temporalDate;
    }
    /**
     * @param temporalDate the temporalDate to set
     */
    public void setTemporalDate(Time temporalDate) {
        this.temporalDate = temporalDate;
    }

}
```

### Hibernate Main :-

```
package com.test.manytomany.main;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.test.manytomany.domain.TemporalTest;

public class TemporalTestMain {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println(" Transaction Started " );
        TemporalTest temporalTest = new TemporalTest();
        temporalTest.setTemporalID(1);
        Time d1 = new Time(55,50,50);
        System.out.println(d1);
        temporalTest.setTemporalDate(d1);
        session.save(temporalTest);

        d1 = new Time(50,30,40);
        System.out.println(d1);
        temporalTest = new TemporalTest();
        temporalTest.setTemporalID(2);
        temporalTest.setTemporalDate(d1);
        session.save(temporalTest);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(TemporalTest.class);
        List list = cr.list();
        Iterator iter = list.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            temporalTest = (TemporalTest) iter.next();
            System.out.println(temporalTest.getTemporalID());
            System.out.println(temporalTest.getTemporalDate());
        }
        session.close();
    }
}
```

The below SQL hangs for ever :-

Jun 11, 2014 9:30:27 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists TEMPORAL_TEST

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem but I had missed session.close() method. Once i added session.close() , i am able to run the same program repeatedly without any issues.